# Java RegExp pattern for (

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to form the Regular expressions for the string

```
Duo Eyeshadow, COMPACT(LID/BASE FRAME ASSY)
```

Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[a-zA-Z0-9 &/.\\-{()}]+[,][ a-zA-Z0-9&/.\\-{()}]+\"");
```

The above expression compiles, but is not accepting the `(` in the string. Can any one help me for the exact reg for the above string?

I am giving input as `string data="Duo Eyeshadow, COMPACT(LID/BASE FRAME ASSY)"`

I need the p.matches(data) should be true....,which is not happening

Can someone give me the pattern which allows `(`  and  `)`

Comment: You need to provide more information about the kind of formal expressions you want to match.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I'd expect the first problem to be that the regex requires the first character it matches to be a quotation mark.

Comment: Your regex seems to accept characters between double quote `"` marks. String you provided is not surrounded with `"`. Consider adding code example with simple input, actual result and expected result with little explanation of why such result should be expected.

Comment: can u give me the pattern which allows ( and )? Sure... `^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,/()-]+$`

Comment: Accoring rubular.com the `&/`will run into an error.

Comment: if i remove the ( and ) from the string and replace with "-" i am getting true.i couldnt give the pattern for"(" and ")"

Comment: Your regex should be able to accept `(` without problems. I suspect that you are not telling us everything. I will ask again: post example which reproduces your problem. Now we can only guess what is wrong with your approach.

Comment: @reporter: i am getting correct answe with" &/" my problem is with jst "(" and ")"

Comment: @pshemo: String data = "DuoEyeshadow,COMPACTLI(DBAS)EFRAMEASSY";  can u give methe pattern which accepts above string and returns true

Comment: Is that entire string? No parts in between `"`? Your regex expect matching part to start and end with `"` because of `\"`. If you don't need this then maybe get rid of `\"` from your pattern `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 &/.\\-{()}]+[,][ a-zA-Z0-9&/.\\-{()}]+")` but this has actually nothing to do with `(` and `)`.

Comment: i think the matches syntax would be `string.matches(pattern)`

Comment: @Jothi why you added `\"` in your regex?

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would be enough to match the above string `Duo Eyeshadow, COMPACT(LID/BASE FRAME ASSY)`,

```
"[A-Za-z ]+,[ A-Za-z(/)]+"
```

**Code:**

```
String s = "Duo Eyeshadow, COMPACT(LID/BASE FRAME ASSY)";
boolean out = s.matches("[A-Za-z ]+,[ A-Za-z(/)]+");
System.out.println(out); //=> true
```

OR

```
String s = "DuoEyeshadow,COMPACTLI(DBAS)EFRAMEASSY";
boolean out = s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 &/.{()}-]+,[ a-zA-Z0-9&/.{()}-]+");
System.out.println(out); //=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to match `(` and `)` in regexps is to use `[(]` and `[)]`. This works with most regexp engines, is pretty easy to read and doesn't blow up unexpectedly.

The other option is `\(` but that has to become `"\\("` when you use it in strings (to escape the backslash which has a special meaning in Java Strings; totally unrelated to regexp but gets in the way).

And in some regexp slang, `\(` actually means the same as `(` in the Java regexp engine (i.e. the start of a group) which makes things even more confusing which is another reason why I try to avoid it.

Comment: That is not the problem here. `(` is always placed in side character class `[...]` so it is escaped.

Comment: @Pshemo: You misunderstood my answer. `[\\(]` will match the two characters `backslash` and `(`. I'm saying you *either* use `[(]` *or* `\\(`.

Comment: And OP is using `[(]` but with additional characters inside which will also be escaped like `{`. There is no `[\\(]` in OP regex so there is no need to explain it here.

Comment: There is `[..\\-(..]` but that is not problem because `-` needs to be escaped here.

Comment: thaks for ur suggestions